# What does Mobile browsers render pages in a virtual "window" mean

Tags: css, html, meta-tags

I read on a [website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) the following:

> Mobile browsers render pages in a virtual "window" (the viewport),
>   usually wider than the screen, so they don't need to squeeze every
>   page layout into a tiny window (which would break many
>   non-mobile-optimized sites). Users can pan and zoom to see different
>   areas of the page.

I don't have much of experience, can someone please explain using other terms. I didn't understand how the mobile create a viewport and then let the user to zoom in that viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all means that the page it will fit the mobile's screen when using the meta tag , something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

So instead of the page showing like desktop view - all shrinked - and then you have to zoom in (a lot) to read, you can just simply scroll, because the content will fit properly the mobile/tablet's screen.

You may or may not be able to zoom depending on the property you use on the meta tag viewport.

This `maximum-scale=1` will allow you to block zoom if your `initial-scale=1`